# Grails - SpringSecurityPlugin not generating controllers

Tags: grails, spring-security

i am new to Grails.

I followed the instructions to install SpringSecurityPlugin (version 2.0:RC2) and executed the command:
**grails s2-quickstart User Role**,
that is supossed to generate among other files: **LoginController** and **LogoutController**, but these controllers are not being generated in grails-app/controllers or any other directory into the project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See "Changes in generated classes" in http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/newInV2.html

Comment: Fixed. Long live the link.